# `error: unpack requires a string argument of length 4` error when using syncdb to migrate

Tags: django, python-2.7

Never seen anything like it. When I do `python manage.py syncdb` in a Django app on the Ubuntu terminal, I'm seeing:

`error: unpack requires a string argument of length 4`

I'm not sure what that means or how to fix it.

---

```
>     Traceback (most recent call last):
>       File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/myenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py",
> line 222, in run_from_argv
>         self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
>       File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/myenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py",
> line 250, in execute
>         translation.activate('en-us')
>       File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/myenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/translation/__init__.py",
> line 90, in activate
>         return _trans.activate(language)
>       File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/myenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py",
> line 183, in activate
>         _active.value = translation(language)
>       File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/myenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py",
> line 172, in translation
>         default_translation = _fetch(settings.LANGUAGE_CODE)
>       File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/myenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py",
> line 133, in _fetch
>         res = _translation(globalpath)
>       File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/myenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py",
> line 127, in _translation
>         t = gettext_module.translation('django', path, [loc], DjangoTranslation)
>       File "/usr/lib/python2.7/gettext.py", line 493, in translation
>         t = _translations.setdefault(key, class_(fp))
>       File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/myenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py",
> line 75, in __init__
>         gettext_module.GNUTranslations.__init__(self, *args, **kw)
>       File "/usr/lib/python2.7/gettext.py", line 180, in __init__
>         self._parse(fp)
>       File "/usr/lib/python2.7/gettext.py", line 273, in _parse
>         magic = unpack('<I', buf[:4])[0]
>     error: unpack requires a string argument of length 4
```

And `manage.py` just contains:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import sys

if __name__ == "__main__":
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "myapp.settings")

    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line

    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
```

Comment: Please let us know the version of Django you're using, and post the traceback for the exception. (If you don't see a traceback, add `--traceback` to the syncdb command.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the traceback (thanks :) ), the problem stems from Django loading its translation files (Gettext .mo files).

Since `magic = unpack('<I', buf[:4])[0]` errors out with "error: unpack requires a string argument of length 4", `buf` is probably shorter than 4 bytes. That probably (just an assumption here) means there's a truncated .mo file somewhere that Django attempts to load and fails.

I'd suggest trying to recreate the project's virtualenv, if that's an option – or as a band-aid, you could disable Django's i18n bits for the time being in the settings. (`USE_I18N = False`)

Comment: Thanks for chiming in buddy. Since I'm just experimenting around on a test server, I'm going to go with a fresh virtualenv install - it's definitely an option. I'll post back what happens. Fingers crossed! I do think it's a ver agnostic problem.